# Populate the on-topic list

Tags: feature-request, scope

I was looking at the on-topic list of the site, and there [wasn't much to look at](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). How about adding some stuff there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's a great point! I'll put up an announcement for a Meta discussion about that later today.